# Will abandoned session ids have any impact on azure service bus performance?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Scenario:
We send messages (of same type) to **a queue** from multiple senders. Each sender will send groups of messages that are tied together by a unique session id for a given group. There is not limit to number of groups. On the consuming side, we have multiple receivers.

Question:
If receivers do not call *await session.CloseAsync()* on the last message in a group, will there be any performance implications down the road in our instance of azure service bus?

Answer (score 0):

With message sessions, closing a session indicates that any other receiver can pick up the session and continue processing (message sessions can be only processed by a single receiver to ensure FIFO semantics). You should *strive* to close the session when it's no longer needed or is over. That way your client can start processing messages for another session that is pending processing.

There is a good [sample with explanation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-servicebus-messaging-samples/tree/master/Sessions) how sessions work from Clemens you might have a look at as well.

Comment: After a receiver processes all current messages in a queue for a given session, it seem to wait for about 60 seconds before message receivers's OnCloseSessionAsync method is called, which is actually causing following exception which is being reported in SessionHandlerOptions.ExceptionReceived handler. Here are the details of exception: options.ExceptionReceived: Action: OnCloseSessionAsync Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1. ...

Comment: Also, once the session is closed by the receiver (by service bus client), it seem to handle other sessions fine. I am not closing sessions explicitly. So the question is: Does this have any performance implications?

Comment: @Raghu, you should update your question with all this details

Comment: Why? The question is very clear (even without above details). The above answer talks about guidance and does not address my question. However one small correction: The exception that I received was of my own doing. I found a bug. However my question regarding abandoned session still stands.

Comment: Think for a second. If you don't close the session explicitly, the client is waisting its resources to sit idle and wait for the next message for that session or for the connection to drop, rather than processing another session's messages.

Comment: Yes, I get that on the client side, which I explained in my comments above. However my question is on the server side. How badly does this affect the my service bus instance in azure? Would I run into any issues down the line?

Comment: "my service bus instance"? Sorry mate, I'm lost here. Service bus instance of what? Namespace, entity? Read the doco. Usually, when there are negative things with some pattern, they are well described. Cheers.